# Dash library is installed but does not work

Tags: package-repositories, libraries, dash.el

[image]

Dash appears to be installed (it shows as status "dependency") but I cannot use it:

```
(-sum '(1 2 3))
==> progn: Symbol’s function definition is void: -sum
```

I tried to delete and reinstall but dependency won't let me delete it.

How can I fix this situation?

(I installed dash on another computer and it works fine)

Comment: Can you find something like `dash-20230714.723` in your `elpa` directory (`C-h v package-user-dir` to find out where it is)?

Comment: Yes. I found it in `~/.emacs.d/elpa`: dash-20230714.723

Comment: Check your `load-path` with `C-h v load-path` - does it contain an entry for `dash`? Something like `/home/zeynel/.emacs.d/elpa/dash-20230714.723/`? You might try to restart your Emacs.

Comment: Yes, it is in the load-path: `"~/.emacs.d/elpa/dash-20230714.723"` I restarted emacs but I still get the same error: `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function -sum)  (-sum '(1 2 3))`

Comment: What does `M-: (featurep 'dash)` say? If `nil`, try `M-: (require 'dash)`. Try `C-h f -sum RET`. See if the directory above contains a `dash.elc` or `dash.el`. Try with `emacs -Q`: it may be that your init file is screwed up.

Comment: Thanks! `M-: (require 'dash)` fixed it. Now it works.

Comment: That's a decent workaround for now, but you should figure out why that happened and fix it: it may be a missing autoload or it may be that your init file is screwed up (or a dozen other reasons) - but you should investigate and fix it properly.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right about my init file (`.emacs`, right?) being corrupted. I did not copy it to my new computer I'm building a new one.